# Getting rid of order status within the WooCommerce My Account - Orders Page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

I'd like to hide the Status columns within `My Accounts - Orders` *(where it shows processing, refunded, etc...)*.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Here is a screenshot showing the account status column:

[image: Here is the image showing the account status]

Thanks.

Here is the code that's currently in my file (`my-orders.php`)

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );

$customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => $order_count,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
) ) );


/**
 * This is the entire "Recent Orders" section below my subscriptions. It has been commented out
 *
if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_title', __( 'Recent Orders', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></h2>

    <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( $my_orders_columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>

**/
```

Comment: Updated my answer for template version 2.5.0 … Did it worked for you?

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec. I didn't realize my file was out of date. Should I just copy over all of the files from the Woocommerce My Accounts folder to my child theme folder? Should I copy over other folders besides My Accounts? This is the first time that WooCommerce has made a big update since I signed up, so I'm not sure what the best way is for me to update and still keep my previous changes.

Comment: If not needed, you can keep your woocommerce version (keeping all your changes). In your child theme, if you don't have the woocommerce folder, create it, add a subfolder named `myaccount` and copy to this subfolder the file that you will find in your plugin folder woocommerce > templates > myaccount > my-orders.php… open/edit the file and comment the line like in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to override **`myaccount/orders.php`** WooCommerce via your active theme.

For that, if not done, you will need to copy from **`woocommerce`** plugin folder, a subfolder named **`templates`** to your active child theme (or theme) and to rename it **`woocommerce`** *(see [**this related docs**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/))*.

After that you find inside that new **`woocommerce`** folder in **`myaccount`** subfolder a template named **`orders.php`**.

Open/edit **`orders.php`** template and replace the code by this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Orders
 *
 * Shows orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>

<?php if ( $has_orders ) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) :
                    if( $column_name != 'Status' ){ // added this line
                ?>
                    <th class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php
                    } // and this too
                endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) :
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order );
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
                ?>
                <tr class="order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) :
                        if( $column_name != 'Status' ){ // added this line
                    ?>
                        <td class="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number(); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo sprintf( _n( '%s for %s item', '%s for %s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                    $actions = array(
                                        'pay'    => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_checkout_payment_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'view'   => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_view_order_url(),
                                            'name' => __( 'View', 'woocommerce' )
                                        ),
                                        'cancel' => array(
                                            'url'  => $order->get_cancel_order_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ),
                                            'name' => __( 'Cancel', 'woocommerce' )
                                        )
                                    );

                                    if ( ! $order->needs_payment() ) {
                                        unset( $actions['pay'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( ! in_array( $order->get_status(), apply_filters( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', array( 'pending', 'failed' ), $order ) ) ) {
                                        unset( $actions['cancel'] );
                                    }

                                    if ( $actions = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', $actions, $order ) ) {
                                        foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) {
                                            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php
                        } // added this too
                    endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_account_orders_pagination' ); ?>

    <?php if ( 1 < $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce-Pagination">
            <?php if ( 1 !== $current_page ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--previous button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page - 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Previous', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $current_page !== intval( $customer_orders->max_num_pages ) ) : ?>
                <a class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-Button--next button" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_endpoint_url( 'orders', $current_page + 1 ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Next', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">
            <?php _e( 'Go Shop', 'woocommerce' ) ?>
        </a>
        <?php _e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_orders', $has_orders ); ?>
```

Save, you are done. This code is tested and working.

---

**Update:** for prior versions of woocommerce 2.5.x, the template file is named **`my-orders.php`** and you have just to comment one line in template code:

```
    // 'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
```

Here is an extract of this template with the commented line in the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * My Orders
 *
 * Shows recent orders on the account page.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-orders.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you (the theme developer).
 * will need to copy the new files to your theme to maintain compatibility. We try to do this.
 * as little as possible, but it does happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will.
 * be bumped and the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
$my_orders_columns = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', array(
    'order-number'  => __( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-date'    => __( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ),
    // 'order-status'  => __( 'Status', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ),
    'order-actions' => '&nbsp;',
) );
```

---

Reference: [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Thanks! The new WooCommerce file is my-orders.php instead of orders.php (since they released an update a few months ago) & the code within the file is in a different format from it was before. Can I still insert the code you pasted here? I updated my post with the code I currently have in my file.

Comment: @@Mary I have just added an update now for old version template **`my-orders.php`**.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would probably be just to hide that column via CSS -- If that column has a unique ID or the TD's have a class you could target with display:none, that'd probably take care of what you'd need.

Alternatively, you could probably also hide it by hooking into the woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns filter.

Something like this (untested)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_columns', 'my_custom_function_name', 10);

function my_custom_function_name($order){
  unset($order['order-status']);
  return $order;
}
```

I'm sure that exact code won't work, but I'll bet it gets you pretty close.